# Antialiasing in Qt's QGraphicsScene make overlapping lines darker

Tags: qt, pyside

When using anti-aliasing rendering in Qt's `QGraphicsScene`, there is a behavior that makes drawings appear not as expected: overlapping lines become darker. I could not see any description of this behavior in the documentation, and I cannot find a way to disable it.

For example if I want to draw such a polygon:

[image: Polygon]

Because of the number of points, it is impossible not to have overlapping lines - fine. But because anti-aliasing is activated, some borders appear 'thicker' than others.

Is there any way to avoid this and have anti-aliased lines that can overlap and yet at the same time be rendered without getting darker?

I know of course that I can redefine the `paint()` function and draw manually individual lines that do not overlap, but this is what I want to avoid. I am using Pyside and this would significantly slow down the application, due to the high frequency at which `paint()` is being called.

**EDIT** Fixed by defining the object shape using `QPainterPath` / `QGraphicsPathItem` instead of `QPolygon` / `QGraphicsPolygonItem`. In that case the `moveTo` function allows to avoid lines that overlap.

Comment: You can disable anti-aliasing altogether, but I think that's not an option for you, right?

Comment: How are you drawing that polygon? If you use `QGraphicsPathItem` you can move your pen without drawing. So you don't have to overlap lines. Otherwise, I don't think it's possible because of the way antialiasing works.

Comment: Daniel: you are right, this is not an option.

Avaris: At the moment all my symbols are `QGraphicsPolygonItem`s, but I think you are right, using `QGraphicsPathItem` would be more clever. I will try it. Thanks !

Comment: You should post an answer and accept it instead of adding answer to the question text.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you could try is adding half a pixel to your coordinates (not dimensions). This fixed the anti-aliasing issue for me.

```
XCoord = int(XValue) + 0.5
YCoord = int(XValue) + 0.5
```

Also make sure that before that you have integer pixel values.

Comment: But when you zoom-in (change the scale), at some point you may see the two distinct lines, no?

Comment: @maxime-esa never tried it. But since you are offsetting all lines by the same amount, one could suppose that they would still be indistinguishable.